# how can I add or edit lot of global attributes with ncatted?

Tags: bash, netcdf, nco

Is there a convenient way to edit and/or add a lot of global attributes using **ncatted**?
Maybe through specifying every *att_dsc* into an external file and pass it as an argument?

EDIT:
My not working solution was: `ncatted -h $(cat global_attributes | xargs -d '\n') file.in file.out`

Whereas in the `global_attributes` I have a list of *att_dsc* as follow:

```sh
-a institution,global,m,c,"Super Cool University"
-a source,global,c,c,"My Awesome Radar"
-a contributors,global,c,c,"Enrico Fermi, Galileo Galilei, Leonardo Da Vinci"
```

The issue here seems to be the quotes enclosing strings with more than one word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ncatted` supports two complementary methods for large scale attribute modification: regular expressions and multi-options. All variable that fit a regular expression can have their attributes modified simultaneously, and the `-a aed_sct` option can be used multiple times per invocation:

```
ncatted -a units,temperature.?,o,c,kelvin -a foo,bar,o,c,davegrohl in.nc out.nc
```

This is all documented [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncatted).

Edit: Just noticed that the OP wants global attributes. There is an NCO-wide option --glb_att_add that may do well here, since the options can be separated by colons. Documented [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#gaa).

```
ncks --glb machine=${HOSTNAME}:created_by=${USER}:... in.nc out.nc
```

Edit 20210907: Just noticed you updated your question with a clever use of `xargs`. You are so close to solving this! Try preceding each double quote in your input file with a backslash, e.g., `\"foo bar\"` This should keep the quote intact so the shell passes the arguments correctly.

Edit 20210910: As mentioned in the comments below, simply substituting the results from xargs directly on the command line fails to work (why?). However, a simple workaround is to use `xargs` to construct the command string, and execute that string with `eval`, like this:

```
cat > opt.txt << EOF
-a institution,global,o,c,\'Super Cool University\'
-a source,global,o,c,\'My Awesome Radar\'
-a contributors,global,o,c,\'Enrico Fermi, Galileo Galilei, Leonardo Da Vinci\'
EOF

opt=$(cat opt.txt | xargs)
cmd="ncatted -O ${opt} in.nc out.nc"
eval $cmd
```

Note the use of backslashes to protect the quotes in the options file from the shell. Also, GNU `xargs` behaves differently than MacOS, so care should be taken formulating any arguments to it. Nevertheless the above procedure works for me.

Comment: thanks Charlie! I was indeed wondering if there is a smarter way to call `-a aed_sct` multiple times without writing every argument to the command line; maybe by specifying the entries into a file?
Also, what does OP mean? Thanks

Comment: OP means "original post". You can store the entries in a file and use Awk or Perl or Python to read your file and assemble and submit the correct ncatted command.

Comment: Thank you very much, Charlie! I have accepted the answer; however, I also thought that the backslashes would have solved it but they didn't. There must be something hidden in how xargs behaves because if I just copy/paste those commands into an ncatted command works; if I instead parse them with xargs, I get "ERROR received 3 filenames; need no more than two".

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, too. It seems to be a characteristic of the shell rather than quirky behavior by xargs, though. I'm still interested in solving this since it would be helpful for other users.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, Charlie. I just went back to this. It works like a charm! cheers
SG